# Railstutorial.org - Chapter 3: Application Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

Working through the tutorial, I am having problems getting the application to display and receive the message "No application seems to be running here!".  I received the following message when attempting to run it on Cloud9:

> /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in `': uninitialized constant ActionController (NameError)

The error focuses on the application controller but I am unsure what it is wrong:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
# Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
# For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using this full command?

```
$ rails server -b $IP -p $PORT
```

I am at roughly the same spot in the tutorial and get the error you are seeing if I simply type

```
$ rails server
```

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being that I was on the wrong directory which was causing the issue.  Going to the sample_app directory corrected it.